# PCB impedance calc and clearance

Tags: rf, characteristic-impedance

I am using Altium Designer and it has a nice impedance calculator which tells you the required track width for a desired impedance given the layer stack you have configured.
So if layer 1 and layer 3 are ground planes and you place an RF signal track on layer 2 it will need to be x mm wide for 50 ohm impedance. (0.1mm in my case) Great.

What is not mentioned is the necessary clearance from the signal track to other tracks (probably also GND) on the same layer.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Compare microstrip/stripline to coplanar waveguide or edge-coupled differential pair.

Comment: Please elaborate Tim

Comment: @DavidG you asked Altium to deisgn something – a trace for a microstrip, probably – other PCB waveguides have different constraints at distances (for example, if you design a 100Ω differential coplanar waveguide, the design will incorporate inter-trace distance). A single-ended microstrip line has only constraints for groundplane-trace distances and the constraint that "adjacent" traces not be "too" close; "too" more or less depends on how much coupling you can live with. General rule of thumb, 20× the substrate height as horizontal distance should be enough; at that point other mechanisms of

Comment: unintended coupling outweigh the effect of proximity.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers